# regular expression to reverse text order separated by :

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, replace, reverse

I have these html title tags with titles separated by some : (maybe two or three or four, or whatever), and I need to reverse their order like the following example:

```
<title>text1: text2: text3: text4 | sitename</title>
```

sometimes they are more or less : I mean more or less only text1, 2 ,3 or more than text4 separated by :

output:
    text4: text3: text2: text1 | sitename

P.S. I use notepad++ and I need to edit this in bulk for many files..

Thanks,

Comment: do you want it to be done in notepad++ or by code..?

Comment: notepad++ is easier for me..  if by code, and can be done in bulk for multiple files, I am with you, but please tell me which Windows program to use and what are the steps..  thanks

Comment: @Mike - is this still an open issue for you or did you find a work around?

Comment: thx Zack for the feedback..  still open issue..  many told me np++ doesn't do that, and I am not familiar with scripting languages and programming, so I am open for any software that could do that in bulk..  to reverse the order of whatever in the title tag in many html files, that are separated with :  thanks

Comment: do you have Java installed on your computer?  You can confirm this by opening a command prompt and typing in "java -version".  If you get something back, let me know what version is listed.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via Notepad++ (I'm using version 6.1.2) but it's not very pretty...

Using regular expression find replace you can do the following...

Find:

> <title>(.*?)?: (.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?: )?(.*?) \| (.*?)</title>

Replace:

> <title>$11: $10$9$8$7$6$5$4$3$2$1 | $12</title>

BUT it comes with a warning. This assumes that your list of :textA items will never be longer than 11 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try below in Firebug console :)

```
var str="text1: text2: text3: text4 | sitename";
var arr=str.split(":");
var output=" ";
for(m in arr){
  output=arr[m]+output;
}
console.log(output); // returns required output for you
```

Comment: sorry Umesh, I am new to this..  you mean Firebug console extension in Firefox?  if so, where in it do I add this code to generate what I need? and by the way those "text1: text2" etc. are changing.. this is just an example..  and finally I need it to edit bulk files..

Comment: I installed firebug 1.8.4b1 in Firefox, and opened the page I need to edit, my question is: 1- Where do I add the code you provided to generate the changes? 2- how can it be done for bulk files (thousands of files?  Thanks